# What is the etymology and usage of 爱不释手

Tags: etymology, chengyu

## 爱不释手

`be so fond of something that one will not let it out of one's hand`

---

So I'm guessing 爱 would be the being fond of something and the 不释手 would be the not letting go. I feel like it's missing structure like it should be something like 他爱他的{Object}不释手

Is there anything more to this saying and how would it be used in practical speech?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

爱不释手 is idiom in Chinese. You cannot split and use it. In most time, we use it as adjective or adverb to describe that you love something very much.

Common Usage:

- 爱不释手的{Object}
- 他对他的{Object}爱不释手
- {Object}让我爱不释手

Sorry ,I miss the etymology:

南朝·梁·萧统《陶渊明集序》：“余爱嗜其文，不能释手。”

Answer (score 2):

“爱不释手”usually used to describe that someone like something so much,and can't bear to put it down. it is an adjective to describe small things that you like .for example, when you get a watch for Christmas ,you can say " 我对这个手表爱不释手"means "you like the watch so much,that you keep touching or looking at it" and the "something"should be of small size and not a living thing .

Answer (score 1):

爱不释手:

Can be explained as: 释：放下。喜爱得舍不得放手。
Its origins are noted as: 南朝·梁·萧统《陶渊明集序》：“余爱嗜其文，不能释手。”
And has the following usage notes: 补充式；作谓语、状语、宾语；含褒义，表达喜欢物件

Source: http://dict.baidu.com/s?wd=%E7%88%B1%E4%B8%8D%E9%87%8A%E6%89%8B

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is something missing but for reason, you know in Chinese, four has special meaning, people learned that there are four directions, North, East, South, West, so four means something just fine. in other hands, the pronunciation of four is similar with the pronunciation of death in Chinese, so four is good, but the pronunciation of four is bad, you can take the meaning of four, but avoid to speak it out.

So most famous saying in Chinese has four words, this one missed something just for align.

It should be: 爱 something, 不(愿意)放手

You love something, you don't want it to get out of your hand. You can not say love someone, do not want to let him/her go, only for something.

I bought a new cellphone, and I like it very much, you can say: 刚买的新手机太酷了，简直爱不释手,

small toy, cellphone, art craft, only something that can be held in your hand.

Answer (score 1):

【爱不释手】means love this object so much, doesn't want to put it away
Example: 我爱这个手机爱不释手

Comment: `我爱这个手机爱不释手` is even *not* grammatically correct in written language ...